# SetUnhandledExceptionFilter : Continue execution 1 opcode further

Tags: delphi, exception

I'm working on an Xbox1 emulator in Delphi, and because I run the games on the local CPU I have to create a failsafe for ring0 instructions that can occur inside the game-code.

To be able to trap these instructions, I've learned that SetUnhandledExceptionFilter can register a function that's going to be called on non-Delphi exceptions (provided I set JITEnable to a value above 0). The signature of the registered callback function reads :

```
function ExceptionFilter(E: LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS): Integer; stdcall;
```

Inside that function, I can test for illegal instructions like this :

```
// STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION = $C0000096
if E.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode = STATUS_PRIVILEGED_INSTRUCTION then
```

One of the offending instructions is WVINDB ($0F,$09) which I can detect like this :

```
 // See if the instruction pointer is a WBINVD opcode :
 if  (PAnsiChar(E.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress)[0] = #$0F)
 and (PAnsiChar(E.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress)[1] = #$09) then
```

This all works (provided I run this *outside* the debugger) but I can't get the code to execute beyond the failing instruction - I tried it like this:

```
  begin
    // Skip the WBINVD instruction, and continue execution :
    Inc(DWORD(E.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress), 2);
    Result := EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    Exit;
  end;
```

Alas, that doesn't work. Actually, I would have used the real instruction pointer (E.ContextRecord.Eip), but somehow the entire ContextRecord doesn't seem populated.

What can I do so this *does* work as intended?

PS: When running with the debugger, I would expect this code to end up in my ExceptionFilter routine, but it doesn't - it only works without the debugger; Why's that?

```
DebugHook := 0; // Act as if there's no debugger
// Trigger a privileged instruction exception via this ring0 instruction :
asm
  WBINVD
end;
// Prove that my exception-filter worked :
ShowMessage('WBINVD succesfully ignored!');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetUnhandledExceptionFilter seems to be some kind of Delphi wrapper, maybe you have more luck if you do it directly?

You can register your own Exception handler with [AddVectoredExceptionHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679274%28VS.85%29.aspx), this will call a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681419%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function that gives you an [EXCEPTION_POINTERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679331%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure. The Context member of that structure returns ao EIP which you can modify.

If you return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION in the Callback execution continues at the given EIP.

Comment: Also, SetUnhandledExceptionFilter is a kernel API : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Oh, and reading the documentation, it looks like you're right about the Context member, but as I said already, it's not populated! Only the ExceptionRecord seems sane - the ContextRecord looks uninitialized.

Comment: @PatrickvL: it's available for XP and higher (see MSDN). Regarding SetUnhandledExceptionFilter the MSDN docs say:  pointer to a top-level exception filter function that will be called whenever the UnhandledExceptionFilter function gets control, and the process is not being debugged. AddVectoredExceptionHandler does work within the debugger so give it a try!

Comment: AddVectoredExceptionHandler he? I'll give it a try. It seems available since WinXP, which is good. (Before, I mixed it up with AddVectoredContinueHandler, which is only available since Vista).